# Understanding php code

Tags: php

I need help trying to split up this code into a way such that I can add more code into each of the true and false statements. The code is below:

```
if(($modify?modify_event($event_id,"$year-$month-$day","$hour:$minute:00",$title,$desc):
            $event_id = create_event("$year-$month-$day","$hour:$minute:00",$username,$title,$desc))) 
        {
```

Comment: Just split the code up into a regular if/else. The ternary statement in the if which uses the result from `create_event` is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($modify) {
            $result = modify_event($event_id,"$year-$month-$day","$hour:$minute:00",$title,$desc);
}
else {
            $event_id = create_event("$year-$month-$day","$hour:$minute:00",$username,$title,$desc);
            $result = $event_id;
}
if ($result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean more than a single statement, then:

```
if($modify){
  modify_event($event_id,"$year-$month-$day","$hour:$minute:00",$title,$desc);
  //more code here
}
else{
  $event_id = create_event("$year-$month-$day","$hour:$minute:00",$username,$title,$desc);
  //more code here
}
```